# UITests: How to find UIBarButtonItem by accessibilityIdentifier with predicate?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

This is how i set it in code:

```
let userBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: userIcon, 
                                        style: .Plain, 
                                        target: self, 
                                        action: Selector("userButtonTapped:"))
userBarButtonItem.accessibilityIdentifier = "userBarButtonItem"
```

And then inside `UITestCase` I need to find this using:

```
XCUIApplication().otherElements["userBarButtonItem"] //doesnt work, and the reason is:
```

> Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - No matches found for "userBarButtonItem" Other

Is there a way how to find this for instance using predicate?

Comment: Did you get a answer to it ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, still looking for answer...

Answer (score 3):

`UIBarButtonItem` does not implement `UIAccessibilityIdentification`, so setting `accessibilityIdentifier` doesn't work.

Instead try

`userBarButtonItem.accessibilityLabel = "userBarButtonItem"`

And then in test case

`XCUIApplication().buttons["userBarButtonItem"]`

This should work.

**UPDATE :**

Now UIBarButtonItem does conforms to UIAccessibilityIdentification, so all these not required.

Comment: Now UIBarButtonItem does conforms to UIAccessibilityIdentification.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiaccessibilityidentification

Comment: UIBarButtonItem does implement UIAccessibilityIdentification, so you can add accessibilityIdentifier from User Defined runtime attributes.

Comment: Well, on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem definitely says that if conforms, but in code it actually doesn't :(

Comment: Actually you are right, accessibilityIdentifier still doesn't work, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:UIString(@"Sign In") style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(submitPressed:)];

 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.accessibilityLabel = @"registration-submit-button";
```

Then I found it via

```
app.navigationBars.buttons["registration-submit-button"]
```